# How to interupt Array.push with Proxy?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add a side effect every when an array being `push`ed. For example, I want to add `console.log`:

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push(1); // => I want it to work normally, and in addition, it logs 1 to the console
```

How to achieve that? I'm looking for a solution using [`Proxy`](https://javascript.info/proxy) and I have tried [handler.get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) and [handler.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply) but still, can't figure it out.

Comment: you could hijack the Array prototype push function to do this, but I don't know why you can't just create another function that takes an array as a parameter, does something and then pushes to the array.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Imagine I'm adding console.log just for the debugging purpose, and it's on an existing codebase, I want to modify the existing code base as little as possible. Let me try `prototype`.

Comment: @DBS - yes it appears so. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie From what you've suggested I can solve the problem now, do you want to write an answer?

Comment: Overriding base prototypes can be dangerous, everything on `window` including third-party code will use this. Strongly suggest creating a custom func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your initial question...you need to return a closure from the `get` trap. To actually trap this, you would need to use `proxy.push()` instead of `array.push()`, though. For example:

```js
const arr = [];

const arrProxy = new Proxy(arr, {
  get(target, prop) {
    if (prop === 'push') {
      return (...args) => {
        console.log(...args);
        return target[prop](...args);
      };
    }
    return target[prop];
  }
});

arrProxy.push('test');
arrProxy.push('test1', 'test2');
```

Comment: What if what I want is `console.log('test')`, not `console.log(1)`

Comment: Well, `array.push()` can be provided more than one parameter. What would you like to happen if there's more than one value? If we assume there's only ever one parameter, you can just replace `1` with `args[0]` but I wouldn't recommend it. You most likely want to do `console.log(args);` (Updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final answer that I'm comfortable with, it doesn't use `Proxy` by the way.

```js
{

var arr = [];

// add push
arr.push = function (...items) {
  console.log(...items);
  Array.prototype.push.apply(this, items);
};

arr.push('test');
arr.push('test1');

// clean up the push
delete arr.push;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'myPush',
  {
  value : function (...val)
    {
    console.log(...val)
    return this.push(...val)
    }
  })


let aa = []
aa.myPush( 5,123)

console.log('aa = ', aa  )
```

Comment: Let's imagine I'm debugging an existing codebase. There's many `array.push` already and I don't want to change from `push` to `myPush` just for debugging. I want to silently interrupt `push`.